# How to integrate a simple chat into laravel 5

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am going to integrate a chat service for my laravel 5 application, but I'm stuck as to how to accomplish this in a "laravel way", because in order to connect to the chat, one needs the port number and I cannot pass the port number to the laravel router as an argument. I made a simple, yet fully functional web chat according to this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708 article, but now I don't know how and where (which directories) to place the files in, so that I it works correctly in the laravel.
Note: This chat service should be one of the pages of the website, not a separate service.

Any help as to how to structure the service would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!